# Using libcurl to download file from any location on Remote system

Tags: c++, libcurl

Is it possible to Download a file from any location on Remote system using libcurl,if I no the filename and its location on the remote system.

There are example which we can use to download file present in the url path.But how can we download a file stored in some other location?

Comment: You can only read a file if the remote server will actually serve you the file.

Comment: libC**URL** only supports accessing files by URL.